# How to best configure Spring Kafka with SSL through Java Beans (rather than from the application.yml)?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-kafka

I have a Java (11) Spring Boot microservice using the Spring Kafka starter (together with an Axual wrapper, but this is probably not relevant). My business requires authenticating to the cluster using SSL. I have set up things locally and it's all working neatly.

But now I am tasked with organising the project and the configuration in a secure and proper way, which primarily includes separating the SSL keystore, truststore and the passwords from the source code repo. In my local setup I have them in my resources directory as .jks files.

The current setup for storing secrets is using a Spring Config Server that we connect to using Spring cloud. This SCS has a Credhub instance that can be used to store secrets. in another project that uses SSL for an mTLS connection with a third party API, I have stored the certificates in base64 in this credhub, and then load them into a bean when the app boots up. Here I use the Java.net.ssl SSLContext class and the java.security Keystore class to build a keystore and a truststore in code, then inject the SSLContext bean into a RestTemplate bean and without going into the specifics, voila it is configured.

I was hoping to do something similar in Spring kafka. But whereas the Spring RestTemplate can be constructed using a bunch of factory classes that at their base take in this SSLContext object, I struggle to find the way the ConsumerFactory can be configured except by supplying a property in the KafkaProperties that points to an already made .JKS file.

I was looking to build up my SSLContext or simply my KeyStore object in Java, inject it as a Spring bean and use it to configure the factory. Now, the KeyStore class has a 'store(.., ..)' method that can be used to create a .jks file - but this seems a roundabout way of doing it. It just seems a bit hacky to do it that way.

The way I see it, I have a few options.

- A: find a way to inject the SSL config as a bean and configure the factory in code
- B: load the SSL config in java in code, then save it as a file for the Spring Kafka to load normally
- C: Inject the .jks file in the pipeline from a secure location into the container
- D: inject the .jks file into the container on boot-up through another kind of secret storage solution

I prefer option A because I like working the framework and deepening my understanding.

Option B seems, like I said, hacky. But perhaps someone here will tell me it's totally fine. Then I would like to know how best to do this. Do I simply call the .store() in my ConsumerFactory bean before I return it? Can I extend or configure the SpringApplication.run() to maybe execute this creating and storing of the keystore file before loading all the other beans? Any ideas would be welcome.

Option C and D will solve my issue. They may even be the better solutions. But for my own understanding of the framework, if you can help me figure out A (or possibly B) I would love to hear it. If then the conclusion is still "go for C you're better off that way" then at least I know the ins and outs of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but the factory (producer and consumer) has `updateConfigs()`.

```java
/**
 * Update the consumer configuration map; useful for situations such as
 * credential rotation.
 * @param updates the configuration properties to update.
 * @since 2.7
 */
default void updateConfigs(Map<String, Object> updates) {
}
```

For option A, you can inject Boot's auto configured factories into another `@Bean` definition and mutate the configs there.

I don't think the kafka-clients code provides a mechanism to inject your own SSLContext, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I have indeed seen this method. The thing is that the only available properties in the config are the ones that point to a jks file in the file system. I am trying to figure out whether there is a mechanism to inject this keystore/truststore as a Java class, rather than by loading the jks file, but as you mention, it seems like there is no such way in the spring kafka api as of yet.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Spring - all connection activity is delegated to the `kafka-clients`. Unfortunately, it is hard-wired to read the stores from disk - they can't even be fetched from the class path, or an `InputStream` - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7685 - vote it up!! Sadly, the KIP referenced therein seems to have been deleted; the last comment talks about a work around with a custom `KeyStoreProvider`.

Comment: Correction: The KIP has moved: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-398%3A+Support+reading+trust+store+from+classpath